# How to change my top navigation menu with conditional statement

Tags: php, wordpress

I cannot seem to figure out how to replace my top navigation menu (nav id="top-menu-nav") with the WordPress menu that I have already created called "Shop".

I have tried a number of different times replacing the 'menu' with 'top_menu_nav' or 'top_menu' but it doesn't recognize the location to replace the menu with the "Shop" menu.

```
if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'product') !== false){
    wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu' => 'Shop' ) );
}
```

The current code places the 'Shop' menu on the left side of the product page with no style and does not replace the menu that is currently in the header.

Comment: Here is the outcome. Notice the menu is placed at the left-hand side of the screen in blue with no styling.   https://pasteboard.co/Inps6wL.jpg

Comment: How you are calling wp_nav_menu function for top_menu_nav?

Comment: if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'product') !== false){
    wp_nav_menu( array( 'top_menu_nav' => 'Shop' ) );
}

Answer (score 1):

Actually you need to show shop menu for all woocommerce pages. right?

In the menu calling in header, please add

```
if (is_woocommerce()) {
    wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu' => 'Shop' ) );
} else {
    wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu' => 'default menu name' ) );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm curious as to how to implement this. This does not replace the existing menu, only places another menu beside the original menu. This may be an issue with my child header.php file being overridden. I will have to look into this further. Thanks again.